# Event Object in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to type an event (or a message) in one object. There are muiltiple events which are all sent in one object. This object has a `type` property which determines the `data` sent by the event.

This is a minimal example:

```js
type MyEvent<
  EMap extends {[x: string]: unknown},
  T extends keyof EMap = keyof EMap
> = {
  type: T;
  data: EMap[T];
};

interface MyMap {
  Event1: {a: number};
  Event2: {b: number};
}

function onEvent(e: MyEvent<MyMap>) {
  if(e.type === 'Event1') {
    console.log(e.data.a);
  }
}

onEvent({type: 'Event1', data: {b: 1}});
```

The code fails on line 16 (`console.log(e.data.a);`) with

```
Property 'a' does not exist on type '{ a: number; } | { b: number; }'.
Property 'a' does not exist on type '{ b: number; }'.
```

Without the `if`-statement this I'd expect the error (`e.type` is `'Event1' | 'Event2'`), but after it, `e.type` should be `'Event1'`.

**Expected:**

It should fail on the last line.

Comment: That's also not the only error you're getting: `Type 'MyMap' does not satisfy the constraint '{ [x: string]: unknown; }'. Index signature is missing in type 'MyMap'.`

Comment: No, it's the only error. Here's my repl: https://repl.it/repls/IncrediblePepperyDisassembler

Comment: That's not what I'm seeing on TypeScript playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAsiCiA3CA7YAeAUFK8YEMwoIAPYVAEwGcoBvAbRIC4orgAnASxQHMBdFgFcUAaxQB7AO4oAvgBpsUACrEylGiIghxAM1wEiAXiibtevIUwA+KMdqLQkFkoDciivmD4WFsPSV8bjJumNzk7Dr4AMbQcAZ0ikiowACMLLTeUCiCALYARhDswYnIaABM6Xks2fmFxTKYmDrCUcCc4ihQHUloABQQLHA9GHGEVgCUCTicOv0AdI7QhstQAOTDKauT9jg4UR1U4gA2EHNH4jzzHl5z+ONuOA0NmN2lwL20UIss62+bclBrplPlUoCkoDIIfdMEA

Comment: That's weird, but then `interface MyMap {` can be changed to `type MyMap = {`.